# Is there a way to log a JS object except for one key in it?

Tags: javascript

I have a JS object that i want to log to the console but one of its values is 5 million characters of a hashed image so im not really interessted in that. Is there a way to exclude this key from the console log / is there a short form for cloning the object, deleting the value and logging it?

Not a duplicate of "cloning object except for one key" btw

Comment: Given that the answer is “no, other than cloning the object except for that key”, is it in fact a duplicate of that? (You could serialize it to a string directly one way or another I guess, but you’ll lose all of the object inspection console features.)

Comment: One would utilize the [rest property within a destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property) ... for instance like ... `function logObjectWithoutKey(key, obj) { const { [ key ]: suppressed, ...rest } = obj; console.log(rest); }` ... and then e.g ... `logObjectWithoutKey('img', { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz', img: 'a lot of data' });` ... or ... `logObjectWithoutKey('baz', { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz', img: 'a lot of data' });`

Answer (score -2):

One very easy way to do this is by using the spread operator [[MDN Docs]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const yourObject = {id:"something",img: "5M-character-stuff"}
console.log({...yourObject, img: "short-img"});
// logs: {id:"something",img: "short-img"}
```